# How to set the ALE configuration `g:ale_exclude_highlights`?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, plugin-system, plugin-ale, linting

I use `ALE` to check coding style, but I want to **ignore the warning type:`line too long`**, like this picture:
[image]

And I find the related setting `g:ale_exclude_highlights`, this is its explanation in `:help ale` :

```
g:ale_exclude_highlights                             g:ale_exclude_highlights
                                                     b:ale_exclude_highlights

  Type: List
  Default: []

  A list of regular expressions for matching against highlight messages to
  remove. For example:

  " Do not highlight messages matching strings like these.
  let b:ale_exclude_highlights = ['line too long', 'foo.*bar']
```

So,

1. I put `let g:ale_exclude_highlights = ['line-too-long', 'line too long', 'Line too long', 'E501']` in `~/.vimrc`,
2. then open vim again,
3. then check the above settings by `:echo g:ale_exclude_highlights`.

**But the warning highlight still arise.**

My question is:　How to set the ALE configuration `g:ale_exclude_highlights`?

PS. & UPDATE:
MY ALE Config(find in :`:ALEInfo`)

```
Current Filetype: python 
Available Linters: ['bandit', 'cspell', 'flake8', 'flakehell', 'jedils', 'mypy', 'prospector', 'pycln', 'pycodestyle', 'pydocstyle', 'pyflakes', 'pylama', 'pylint', 'pylsp', 'pyre', 'pyright', 'refurb', 'ruff', 'unimport', vulture'] 
Enabled Linters: ['flake8', 'pylint'] 
Ignored Linters: []
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the language/filetype of the corresponding buffer? Could you tell us what is the linter you are using?

Comment: @Vivian De Smedt Thank you for your remind, I've update some related info in the end of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it applies to lines (see [this](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/issues/3054) ALE issue).

I suppose the best is to configure the underlying linter.

For the `flake8` linter I have in `~/.flake8`:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 125
ignore = 
    # E203: whitespace before ':'
    E203,
    # E501: line too long
    E501,
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, can I ask how to configure the underlying checker.